# (Deadline Extended!) Do you have >1k rep on Ask Different? Do you still need a copy of Lion?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, lion

Stack Exchange wants to pay for Lion upgrades for Ask Different's top users. If you've got more than 1000 reputation on Ask Different and you still need to upgrade to Lion, [send me an email](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/7749/abby-t-miller)!

You've got until 5PM New York time on Monday, August 8th to send me an email requesting your upgrade. Please use the words "ask", "different", "lion", and "upgrade" in your subject line so it'll go to a filter I'm watching closely. And, if you would, please stick a link to your Ask Different user profile in the body of the email so I can snoop around.

If you still need to upgrade, but you've only got 900 rep... you've got until Monday to ask, answer, and edit your way up to 1000!

Update:
Seriously, you guys! We really want to buy you your copy of Lion. We've gotten a few requests so far, but we want more. So I'm extending the deadline to **this coming Friday the 12th at 5PM New York time**.

Comment: @Abby The email in your "about me" section and the email in the email section of your profile are different. Is that intentional? Or do they both go to the same place?

Comment: @Kyle They both go to the same place. And I thought the "email" email wasn't visible? Or can you just see it 'cause you're a mod? This house so confusing.

Comment: @Abby The latter - mods can see everything except openid in the profile

Comment: Great Ideas! (I've already got Lion, can I get reimbursed? :P)

Comment: Almost wish I'd waited! Still, great idea!

Comment: Gah I didn't see this "question" in time :-(

Comment: @Nippysaurus: yes, you did! Check the update :) (unless you mean you bought it already)

Comment: Yeah I bought it already :-)

Comment: I've also already bought it but I appreciate the thought. :-)

Comment: You people are so awesome! I just made 1k but I'm not on a Mac so it's not relevant - but you're still awesome for offering it. Wow!

Comment: @Abby Got mine in the mail yesterday - thanks!

Comment: I got mine in the mail too! Thanks!  I was just expecting a Mac App Store redemption code!

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed very generous. I sadly am not going to quite get to 1000 (only been a member for three weeks!) but it is great that you are rewarding people's involvement on the site this way.

Comment: Please email me! I think we can strike a deal.